# How to work with list of data in firebase firestore android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Firestore in that I want all the document in collection as a purpose to show each in my `RecyclerView`. I am able to get the data using this code.

```
 db.collection("resturant_profile").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult()){
                        Log.d("amit",documentSnapshot.getId()+" => "+documentSnapshot.getData());


                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

But I don't now how to get each data of the list separately by making class. I think I should use method

```
documentSnapshot.toObject(someclass);
```

Now I don't know how what type of class to be used.

I read documents, but in that I did't find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Create a model class using the same field names that you want to be inside a document, example:

```
public class Restaurant{

String title, desc;

public Restaurant(){}

public Restaurant(String title, String desc) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc  = desc;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

}
```

And then when fetching do:

```
Restaurant res = document.toObject(Restaurant.class)
```

Comment: Wrong Answer, because it require Class<T> as paramerter showed in android studio, also compilation error occur. messaging error: cannot find symbol class T

Comment: The error is compilation, and the  log is as follows :: error: cannot find symbol class T

Answer (score 0):

you can get each single value by its key like :

```
String categoryId = snapshot.child("categoryId").getValue().toString();
```

then store it in model object like :

```
resModel.setCategoryId(categoryId);
```

Comment: We can not call child method on documentSnapshot

Comment: @Mohammad: OP is using Firestore, while the syntax in your answer is for Firebase Realtime Database.